# "They've grown so much" vs "They've 'been' grown so much"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, expressions

In this sentences the difference is the **been**. I've been seen this two ways to write this same thing. In the translater, the two ways is right. Why?

"They've grown so much" vs "They've 'been' grown so much"

Comment: Where have you seen these? And what are "they"?

Comment: _Grow_ in the sense _cultivate a plant_ can be used in the passive voice; "Roses have been grown in this garden for fifty years". _Grow_ in the sense _become larger_ can't be passive.

Comment: @KateBunting Scientists 'grow' crystals in the lab, or you can do it at home, and later say 'this crystal was grown using the XYZ method'. Seems to follow the plant model some extent (you use an initial 'seed' crystal).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey simple past is grew and the other is present perfect continuous.

Comment: I think you mean: They've been grow**ing** so much. I've been seeing, I've been going to the beach.  Entende agora? Eu tenho estado indo a praia, p. ex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"They have been grown so much" is not grammatical.

"They have grown so much" = Since some time in the past, they have grown a lot.

"They have been grown..." can only be followed by a description of growing conditions, actions, or time:

"They have been grown in a greenhouse"

"They have been grown with pure oxygen."

"They have been grown for three weeks in an incubator."

Comment: He means growing but can't hear it due to native language interference. This happens a lot with Portuguese and Spanish.